# Processing in Eclipse--Cannot access class because it does not export to module core

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

Does anyone have any insight as to why this is failing? I've tried variations of adding the libraries--I'm trying to create a new project, and have the shapes package working in another older project, but trying to isntantiate in this project either of the shapes package or the dance package doesn't work--I get this error.

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
There are now no errors in the Problems tab, but console returns this when I try to run
Error: Could not find or load main class embodiedInteractionDance.MovingRectangle
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: processing/core/PApplet

Comment: Your project folder is decorated with a red exclamation mark, which means that something is wrong with your project settings. See in the _Problems_ view for details and fix it before trying to run it. You have a `module-info.java` file (is that intended?), please include it in your question as text. It might be easier to start without a `module-info.java` file (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_).

Comment: so when I go to look at the problems, it says I'm missing the required libarries core.jar, glugen-rt.jar, etc--but those are already included, os I'm not sure how to make eclipse acknowledge them

Comment: Because you have a module-info.java file you are using the Java module system which requires things to be set up differently. If you delete it the project will revert to the "traditional" way of doing things.

Comment: Okay, so I deleted it--I'm not sure why it was created in the first place to be honest. Sorry--didn't catch the other comment saying it would be easier to delete it,,, been working on this all night. I now try to run it and get an issue > Error: Could not find or load main class embodiedInteractionDance.MovingRectangle
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: processing/core/PApplet

Comment: So, no errors are displayed anymore in the _Problems_ view, right? Please edit your question and include the full error message from the _Console_ view as text. If there are still errors displayed in the _Problems_ view, add those error messages as text to your question instead. If there is still a red exclamation mark than there is something wrong with your project setting that prevents your source code to be compiled (so no main class can be found).